How can I use a jq query to extract a string from this Ansible dictionary?
So I have the following tasks in my playbook
- name: gather package facts
  package_facts:

- name: send packages containing 'fence-agents' to a file
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/leapp/transaction/to_remove
    line: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ ansible_facts.packages | ???????"
  become: true 

Is there anyway to extract a list with all packages which contain the string fence-agents?
I don't want to loop the entire package list as it would increase the playbook run time significantly.

You should provide a simplified and anonymized version of ansible_facts.packages

Why would you want to use an external tool like jq for such an easy task? Ansible does have filter for those kind of purpose already. Your question seems like a X/Y problem as it is currently written.

Q: "Is there anyway to extract a list with all packages which contain the string fence-agents?"
An approach based on the given question example
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts.packages[item] }}"
    loop: "{{ ansible_facts.packages | select('search', regex) }}"
    vars:
      regex: 'fence-agents*'

Similar Q&A

How to get the available Python versions on Remote Node?
Output the common packages installed in all the servers

